# Django REST API & Backbone: Accessing json data for self-referencing model

Tags: backbone.js, django-models, django-rest-framework, self-reference

I am using Django REST API to feed data into Backbone from Postgres database. One of my Backbone collections deals with a self-referencing Category model - categories can be either parent categories or child subcategories. On various pages of the application, I would like to display a dropdown with the category-subcategory pairs (or just category, if parent has no children subcategories); there are about 500 such pairs (see below). The problem is that accessing the categories data from the API using fetch() or getJSON() is very very slow, to the extent that 20-25 seconds are required for the the dropdown to get populated. How can I reduce this latency? Should the database schema for the categories table be different? Should the category django model be different? Should the serializer be different? Should I get the data to the front-end differently?

Below are my current design choices.

Database Categories table:

```
id
name
parentid
```

Django Category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    parentid = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

Serializer (for each category, the parent id will either show as null or display the full parent category):

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parentid')
    depth = 2
```

Backbone view:

```
initialize: function() {
...
    var self = this;
    var promise = $.getJSON('/api/categories.json', function(data) {
        self.categoriesArray = data;
    });
    promise.done(function() {
        console.log('categories available');
        self.showCategories(self.categoriesArray);
    });
...
},

ui: {
    categoriesDropdown: "#categories-tags"
},

showCategories: function(categories) {
    var self = this;
    var text, value;
    _.each(categories, function(item) {
        if (item['parentid']) {
            text = item['parentid']['name'] + "-" + item['name'];
        } else {
            text = item['name'];
        }
        value = item['id'];

        self.ui.categoriesDropdown
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", value)
            .text(text));               
    });
},
```

I am dealing with around 450 categories, and only 100 of them are parent categories. If I completely remove the complexities of parent categories (remove `depth = 2` from the serializer, use only the name of a subcategory for the `text` variable in `showCategories`), the time required to populate the dropdown is almost instantaneous. Does this mean that it would be preferable to have a database table that includes the name of the parent category in addition to the parent category id (e.g. columns `id`, `name`, `parentid`, `parentname`)? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Is it the ajax response that takes 20-25 seconds, or is this time taken when actually looping the data in your `showCategories` function?

Comment: It is the ajax response.